# How to give confirm dialog onsubmit of a form element using javascript function

Tags: javascript

Html code:

```
<form action='save.php' method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  some inputs here...
</form>
```

here validations are working fine. but not the confirm code.
Javascript code:

```
function validate(theForm)
{
    validations here for input fields....
    /*confirm dialog*/
    var sure = confirm("Are you sure to proceed ?");
    if(sure == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return sure;
    }
}
```

confirm displays dialog but onclick of 'ok' button it is not submitting the form is there any way to submit form on confirm dialog using javascript function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: Why not just do `return confirm('Are you sure?')` instead of the whole if-else check?

Comment: A simple inline JavaScript confirm will work. Ex. `<form onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure to proceed ?");">`

Comment: what is not working? [http://jsfiddle.net/b8LrB/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/b8LrB/1/)

Comment: Thanks tewathia it is working fine. :)

Comment: @DipeshParmar Not necessarily, as the function validates all inputs. However, as tewathia stated, the if-else could be replaced with that line.

Comment: @NiksD What was the problem?

Comment: @NiksD, pleas check tewathia answer like right. Thanks.

Comment: @NiksD If an tewathia's answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: It was just the syntax error in my javascript code. But the tewathia's code is optimized. Sorry for my silly mistake. I will take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, answer-ing my comment:

Write your form validation function as:

```
function validate(theForm){
    //validation stuff here
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?');
}
```